# How can I prevent that all subviews are colored blue when embedding into a NavigationLink?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink, navigationlink

I have a rather complex view which I want to embed into a NavigationLink but if I do this all text colors turn blue. If the view would just be an image I would use the modifier renderingMode(.original). But my view consists of multiple stacks, images, icons and texts. Is there some why to prevent the coloring without applying the modifier foregroundColor with the correct color to each view individually?

[image: That's the view]

And that's the code:

```
NavigationLink(destination: BlogView(of: blog)) {
    VStack(spacing: 0) {
        
        HStack {
        URLImage(URL(string: blog.avatarURL)!, content: {
            $0.image
                .resizable()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                .clipShape(Circle())
        })
            .frame(width: 35, height: 35)
        
        Text(blog.username)
            .font(.custom(R.font.quicksandRegular, size: 16))
        
        Spacer()
        
        Image(systemName: "ellipsis")
            .imageScale(.small)
            .foregroundColor(.darkGray)
        }
        .padding(.vertical, 10)
        .padding(.trailing, 5)
        
        HStack(alignment: .top) {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 5) {
                Text(blog.title)
                    .font(.custom(R.font.quicksandRegular, size: 17))
                    .fontWeight(.medium)
                    .foregroundColor(.lightGreen)
            
                Text(blog.text)
                    .font(.custom(R.font.quicksandRegular, size: 14))
                    .lineLimit(3)
            }
        
            Spacer()
        
            URLImage(URL(string: blog.mediaURL)!, content: {
                $0.image
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5))
            })
                .frame(width: 120)
                .clipped()
        }
        
        HStack(spacing: 10) {
            Image(systemName: "flame")
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
            Text("\(blog.likeCount)")
        
            Spacer()
        
            Image(systemName: "text.bubble")
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
            Text("\(blog.commentCount)")
        
            Spacer()
        
            Image(systemName: "arrowshape.turn.up.right")
                .foregroundColor(.gray)
            Text("Share")
        }
        .font(.custom(R.font.quicksandRegular, size: 13))
    }
    .padding(.horizontal, 10)
    .background(Color.white)
    .cornerRadius(10)
}
```

Comment: Sure, but would you add your code?

Comment: @Asperi yep, I updated my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either use `.foregroundColor(.primary)` on your `Text` or check the `NavigationLink` documentation:

> A **button** that triggers a navigation presentation when pressed.

Which leads us to:

```swift
NavigationLink(destination: Text("Destination")) {
    CardView()
}
.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())
```

Comment: I already thought about the `.foregroundColor(.primary)` but then I would have to use it every time and I looked for something more general. The `.buttonStyle(PlainButtonStyle())` modifier is the perfect solution I think. Next time I will check the documentation first. Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean with _every time_? On every `Text`? If yes, no need to do this, you can set `.foregroundColor(.primary)` on your top level `VStack`. Same way as you set the `.backgroundColor(.white)`.

Comment: Styling documentation says: _Indicate how to style the text, controls, and other content contained in a view._ The crucial part here is _contained in a view_. In other words, applied to all subviews.